# Yii2 multiple upload on another model

Tags: yii2

I need help building a simple protocol form with multiple attachments, where the user can change these attachments (files) later. That is, the attachments must have binding to a protocol.

(In this case I created 2 tables: `mod_protocol` and `mod_files`)

How should my code stay so that when I insert a new form, the attachments of this form are written to the mod_files table? (I'm not sure how to build a loop to write the files)

I'm at the beginning of this project, check out my files:

**protocol form**

```
<div class="protocol-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 8]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'files[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true,]) ?>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Save' : 'Save', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

**protocol model**

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\protocol\models;

use Yii;

class Protocol extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'mod_protocol';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name'], 'required'],
            [['name','description'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Nome',
            'description' => 'Descrição'
        ];
    }

}
```

**protocol controlller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Protocol();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**files model**

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\protocol\models;

use Yii;

class Files extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'mod_files';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['filename','protoco_id'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'filename' => 'Nome do Arquivo',
            'protoco_id' => 'Protocolo'
        ];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if file is an array:

```
use yourapp/model/ModFile;
...
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Protocol();

    // I would write some logic, verify this saves first.
    foreach($model->files as $file) {
       $model_file = new ModFile();
       $model_file->file = $file;
       $model_file->save();
    }

    // If successful then save the main model.
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In ActionCreate() of protocol controlller ??

Comment: Yes, in your controller

Comment: Another option is to place that logic in the mode with a beforeSave event. But get the above working first and then migrate to the event if your feeling brave.

Comment: Did this solution work for you? If so, can you select accept answer please. If not, how can I help you further?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been traveling ... I'll try now.

Comment: Dude, it did not work! The record in the "mod_protocol" table has recorded, but in the table "mod_files" has not recorded anything.

Comment: I finally got it, thank you. This topic also helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44819799/how-to-upload-several-files-using-yii2

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it working. For my personal improvement in giving advice,  was I missing something in the example?

Comment: The other post helped me with the loop to upload, and its in the logic to record. Both helped me build my code. ^^